# I want a full time career in the field of security. The following is my plan. Any suggestions or modifications?

Tags: career

Currently, I have two years of experience in the field of IT and IT security. The type of work isn't what I expected when I was a student. Since then, I've asked people who work in this field, who suggested me to get certified.

So, I started preparing for the [CompTIA Security+ certification](http://certification.comptia.org/getCertified/certifications/security.aspx) (I need to refresh my basic knowledge), which I'd like to finish by the end of August 2014. I also want to finish the [CEH V8](http://www.vtc.com/products/Certified-Ethical-Hacker-CEH-v8-Exam-312-50-Tutorials.htm) exam by the end of this year.

Holding these certifications, I'd have a good understanding of theory and the required tools. By mid 2015, I want to obtain the much acclaimed [Offensive Security Certified Professional (OSCP)](http://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-certifications/oscp-offensive-security-certified-professional/) certification.

Am I overdoing things here? Any other suggestions by the mates of this Information Security site?

Comment: Perhaps a better initial question is how is the work not what you expected and what do you expect?  If we don't know what you expect, then we don't know what will prepare you for it, or if a job doing what you expected to be doing even exists.

Comment: This is waaay to broad and opinion based, so I'll close this. My post on our Sec.SE blog has some info which may be useful ( http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/03/presentations-starting-your-security-career-where-can-you-go/ ). You could ask in [chat]

Answer (score 0):

Certifications will only carry weight in certain industries and on certain teams. In my experience, they're great for doing security consulting, but not so much for impressing a company's InfoSec team.

Of the certs you mentioned, the only one that carries weight is the OSCP, and unmentioned CISSP is kind of a standard cert.

What type of security do you want to do? digital forensics? Incident response? In-house security team (defense/blue team)?

The security field has a bunch of cool areas you could get into, it'd be helpful to know where you want to go so we can rescope the question (What is a good career path for X infosec job?)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a newbie to these forums and infact security field. Can you please list me out the "cool areas" or provide me with some links??? I'm in a state of confusion now. :(

Comment: "Cool" is a pretty subjective term. What are you interested in doing?

Comment: I'm Interested in management type of jobs. :)